# SwiftUI for MacOS (not Catalyst) - how to add buttons to navigation bar?

Tags: macos, swiftui

Goal:
Add buttons to navigation bar on a real SwiftUI for MacOS (not Catalyst)

What I did:
Tried navigationBarItem, but found it's not available for MacOS.

Does anyone have a solution? Browsed all possible MacOS SwiftUi projects and didn't find anything simulation. Should be trivial, as this is a very common use case?

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {


        NavigationView {

            Text("Hello, World!")

                .navigationBarItems()
        }





    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

Comment: There is *no* `NavigationBar` on macOS, so you cannot. Just create your pane with buttons at the top.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing in macOS. You could use the NavigationLink.
Check the following code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)) {
                Text("Hello, World!")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've got a view being displayed in a sheet (SwiftUI/macos) in which I use a NavigationStack. That seems to work fine. So you would think that you would be able to add buttons to it. 

I'm new to SwiftUI on macOS; I thought most UI elements would have compatible versions across platforms.